# Waiting for a server task to complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a situation where I have to do a server call from Android and based on the result of the call ( result would be  either true or false) I want to proceed ahead in the code flow and pop a Dialog based on this result. Till the call is complete I don’t wish to proceed ahead in the code flow or logic. In short, I want to carry out a sync operation

At the server side,  I will receive a HTTP Post  request from android client and based on the parameters in the POST I do some processing  by fetching  values from the DB and  return back true or false to android client.

To carry this out correctly on Android side,  I researched and got two options.

1. Using Handler with AsyncTask does not  work in my case because if
   I use AsyncTask with Handler,  the task result will arrive
   sometime in future  in Handler and  the calling function will return
   immediately  whereas I want  the calling function invoking 
   AsyncTask to finish i.e. wait till the server returns backs before I
   proceed ahead .
2. The other option  that I came across was  to use
   AsyncTask get() method . Since I am not carrying out a long running
   task and rather performing a simple calculation on serverside, this
   may not cause a an ANR situation even if I block the UI thread.

   Are there  any better options of carrying this out ?  Is AsyncTask get() here actually one of the correct uses of get() ?

Comment: I think `AsyncTask` is best approach for your design flow. When you get a result you can `publishProgress()` at any point in your HTTP response. Or you can `postExecute()` your result on UI if you like to. All that matters is you are running your code snippet in the background and not using `Handlers` but infact using the same resources of `AsyncTask`. You could also use parallel executor if you like.

Comment: Sounds like a classic task for AsyncTask.